# RECT , passing a custom rect struct into a function that is requireing RECT

Tags: c++, rect

ok so I have a custom rect function. The custom rect is as follows:

```
typedef struct tagRECTEx{
// long left;
// long top;
// long right;
// long bottom;
RECT dimensions;

int width()) {
    return dimensions.right-dimensions.left;
}
int height(){
    return dimensions.bottom - dimensions.top;
}

} RectEx;
```

Now instead of using lets say:

```
RECT windowrect;
windowrect = GetWindowRect(hWnd,&windowrect);
```

I would like it to be this instead:

```
RectEx windowrectex;
windowrect = GetWindowRect(hWnd,&windowrectex);

....
```

Now that won't compile because it cannot convert rectex to tagRECT, ok I get this I understand this.

So for the last few days i've been searching on custom casting and overriding operators.

I'm even trying to implement something like:

```
GetWindowRect(hWnd, (RectEx)&windowrectex);
```

but not matter what i'm doing I just can't figure out how to get this to work.

I want to use my own rect struct as it will autoamticly get the width and height of the rect for me instead of doing rect.right-rect.left and etc.

If you need anymore info about this or anything please let me know.

thank you

Comment: Why not just write some non-member functions taking a RECT argument and returning the width/height? Not everything has to be a member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GetWindowRect` takes `LPRECT` as the second parameter, there is no way to pass `RectEx`.

What you can do to use `RectEx`, you can overload typecasting operator as follows

```
operator LPRECT () const 
{
   return &dimensions;
}
```

However, overloading typecasting is not recommended due to undesired type conversion. Only do when you are sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `RECT` from inside your `RectEx`.

```
RectEx windowrectex;
windowrect = GetWindowRect(hWnd,&windowrectex.dimensions);
```

Alternatively, you can make `RectEx` inherit from `RECT` and remove `dimensions`.

Alternatively, add a conversion operator, `operator RECT*() const` like dbasic suggests. Then you would use:

```
windowrect = GetWindowRect(hWnd,windowrectex);
```